# Adobe CQ5 - Custom Mail Functionality

Tags: email, aem

I have a requirement in Adobe CQ5. I have to create a form with some fields (say a registration form). Now after creating the form I have to mail the details to a particular email. things I need to know are.

1. How to create custom email template?
2. Now using the template to how do I create email with the data captured via form?
3. How to configure the email settings?

Please provide you thoughts on this. Might be helpful to a lot of people.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could use hidden fields on the form to send the body of the message with the rest of the fields. You can also do it with the CQ form components.
2. Here you could do 2 things, one is extending the mailServlet class that is on the src folder in foundation, this is the one that uses the foundation mail action, then you extend or create a custom action for use it with the CQ Form components, or you can implement a servlet with the MailService class.
3. the mail setting using the CQ mail service can be set on the Felix console on the configuration panel, search for the CQ5 Mail Service to set the smtp server, credentials and ports.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar requirements that I met by using a workflow to send the form data. This can all be done using out of the box components from cq.

1.
An example of an email template can be found at /etc/workflow/geometrixx/email/workflow.txt.

```
From: Geometrixx Admin <geometrixx@day.com>
To: ${payload.email}
BCC: tripod@day.com
Subject: Signup for ${payload.fullname}

Dear ${payload.fullname}

Please find your account here: http://www.day.com/
Your password is: ${payload.temppassword}

regards
Geometrixx Team
```

You can mix static text in the email with dynamic values from the form. You can access any field in the form by using it's ID. For example, to get a field's contents with id=comments you would use ${payload.comments} in the template.

2.
Once you have the template built, you can link it to the workflow you have tied to the form. The workflow component you will want to use when building the workflow is called Process Step. In the process tab of that components edit dialog there is drop down. Choose send email from that list. In the arguments field, just add the path to your email template. If you test the form now, you should be receive an email containing whatever form data you wanted.

3.
AJ Olivia was correct in that the mail service can be set in the felix console. It can be found here: HOST:PORT/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.mailer.DefaultMailService